# Set maximum execution time in PHP

Tags: php

I tried to increase the max execution time in my `php.ini` file. It doesn't work, however. Considering the fact that I' ve got a large file (containing 300 pages) I have to download using PHPEXCEL, I did the following in my `php. ini` file:

```
max_execution_time = 999999999     
max_input_time = 9999999    
max_input_nesting_level = 64  
memory_limit = 128M
```

Is there anyone who knows what to do in this situation?

Comment: What size was the file?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you have an error message? How big in terms of MB is your file? I really doubt that `999999999` seconds execution time is not enough to download an Excel file.

Comment: Here is the error message I have: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in <b>C:\wamp\www\clinique\scripts\utilisateur\Classes\PHPExcel\Shared\Font.php</b> on line <b>374</b><br />. the size is 2 MO but when I download I just have 1 KO

Comment: You probably have to ensure that your settings changes are applied, did you resatart the server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 0 :

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

That will disabled the limitation. Don't forget to restart apache after.

You can also user the PHP version :

```
<?php set_time_limit(0); ?>
```

Comment: Thx. Let me try and tell you what.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to valid the answer so.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a limit, then you can use this:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

But only if safe_mode is off, otherwise you can use ini_set:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); // 300 Seconds
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thx, Do I have in that case delete the line max_execution_time: 999999?

Comment: You would replace it yes.

Answer (score 0):

On some of my php scripts that take long time to run I always use the following code at the top:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

---

## Explanation:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

We're telling php the script can run for unlimited time.

```
ignore_user_abort(1);
```

We're telling php to continue running the script even if the user disconnects.
i.e.: closing the browser or disconnect from a SSH session.

Comment: Thx so much. I 'll try and tell you about it